# Data insertion fails after a particular level of values in spark

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-spark

I have created a Apache Spark application which analyze a table from Cassandra and insert back into another table in Cassandra. But after a particular number of insertion (217 records), the insertion is failing and Spark stops abruptly. A I have tried with setting executor memory up to 2g. Is there anything else i should add into the configuration?

Comment: Could you share the code of your program and the errors you are seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue that , there was null value present in my cassandra clustering column .That was the reason for error.